# Module Signing - Msg 916, The server principal is not able to access the database under the current security context

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, certificate

I am using Module Signing concept and trying to execute a certificate signed stored procedure `[master].[dbo].[sp_kill]`. I can verify that proc is signed using `[sys].[crypt_properties]`. Login created from the certificate has `[sysadmin]` server role. EXECUTE permission is granted to all users using below query:-

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON sp_Kill TO [public]
```

Still, when trying to execute the procedure using a low privileged SQL login having `CONNECT` & `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permissions, I am greeted with error

> Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Procedure sp_Kill, Line 38 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   The server principal "Ajay" is not able to access the database "DBA" under the current security context.

The procedure `[master]..[sp_kill]` is referencing a table on another database `[DBA]`.

Below is the code for [sp_kill]:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Kill @p_SpId SMALLINT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('DBA..AuthorizedSessionKiller') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE DBA.dbo.AuthorizedSessionKiller(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), IsDbLevelPermission BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, DbName varchar(125) NULL, LoginName varchar(125) NOT NULL, AddedBy varchar(125) NOT NULL, AddedOn datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE());
    END

    /* something here */

END
```

Following is the code I am using to create Certificate, and add signature to procedure:-

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE [CodeSigningCertificate]
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Query@St@ck'
    WITH EXPIRY_DATE = '2099-01-01'
        ,SUBJECT = 'DBA Code Signing Cert'
GO

CREATE LOGIN [CodeSigningLogin] FROM CERTIFICATE [CodeSigningCertificate];
GO
CREATE USER [CodeSigningLogin] FOR LOGIN [CodeSigningLogin];
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'CodeSigningLogin', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.sp_Kill TO [CodeSigningLogin];
GO
ADD SIGNATURE TO [dbo].[sp_Kill]
    BY CERTIFICATE [CodeSigningCertificate]
    WITH PASSWORD = 'Query@St@ck'
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.sp_Kill TO [public]
GO
```

Still, don't understand why getting Error 916 - Cannot access under current security context. I tried drop/create of the procedure.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: What kind of login is "Ajay"? How is mapped to the database? With RO permissions?

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic It is  a low privileged SQL login having ```CONNECT``` & ```VIEW ANY DATABASE``` permissions. No relation to the ```[DBA] ``` database.

Comment: Did you create the cert/cert-based user in the DBA database as well and give it permissions that allow it to (in this case) create a table?

Comment: Yes. I backed up certificate created on master with a private key and restored it on DBA database. Then created user using the Certificate of DBA.

Comment: @BenThul procedure sp_kill is working fine if I create the table [master] database rather than DBA database. So I am using this approach for now.

Comment: In general, I'd discourage creating objects in master as they get overwritten when you do upgrades. But if you're fine with that, go nuts.